# Best Chicago Font alternative

Tags: winforms

I'm just after reading the "User Interface Design for Programmers 2001" by Joel Spolsky. He suggests Apple Chicago as a good font solution to a WinForms App. I would like to know what can be the best alternative of Apple Chicago font in Windows environment. Do you know any out-of-the-box or free-to-download mono spaced fonts that look elegant?

Comment: Apple Chicago is not available for Windows

Comment: The more examples we get here the less searching people will have in the future.

Comment: Screens and screen fonts have made significant progress since 2001.

Comment: Apple Chicago was *not* a mono-spaced font.  Your question is unanswerable as posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignore this particular outdated and questionable advice. Default desktop fonts have got better since then.

As a normal application, it is not your job to choose fonts. Unless there's a special case where the default font is inappropriate, you should leave it alone, so your app can look and feel like everything else on the desktop, conforming to the user's expectations (and possibly deliberate theming choice).

Answer (score 1):

`Consolas` is one of my favorites.

[image: Consolas Sample]

Comment: Sadly, in some systems its undistinguishable from *Comics Sans*

Comment: Very nice - supports Polish diacritics

Answer (score 1):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_%28typeface%29):

"MacEnvy DB is a free TrueType fonts of similar design sometimes used as surrogates on non-Apple systems."

Comment: Nice - that IS what I'm looking for but I happen to be from Poland, and sadly this font doesn't support our diacritic letters. ąęółćśźżń

Answer (score 1):

I've been quite enamored with Steve Matteson's [Droid family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droid_(font)), released by Ascender Corp. under the Apache license. You do run the risk of looking like a native Android app, but they are available, sharp, and global friendly.

[image: Droid Serif] [image: Droid Sans] [image: Droid Sans Mono]